# Rasa utter_message converting json to string

Tags: python, json, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to convert my response in json format but it is converting it into string.

**Response expected**

```
{
    "recipient_id": "default",
    "data": [{
        "Name": "John",
        "status": "To Be Processed",
        "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-05-31 08:40:55.0"
    }, {
        "Name": "Paul",
        "status": "To Be Processed",
        "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-06-02 16:03:00.0"
    }] };
```

**Response getting**

```
{
    "recipient_id": "default",
    "data": ""[{
        "Name": "John",
        "status": "To Be Processed",
        "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-05-31 08:40:55.0"
    }, {
        "Name": "Paul",
        "status": "To Be Processed",
        "LastUpdatedDate": "2013-06-02 16:03:00.0"
    }]""
};
```

i am using `dispatcher.utter_message` to send response.

Comment: are you using the `rasa-sdk` or the `rasa_core_sdk`? Where exactly do you revieve the message as string? At the rest channel? Would be great if you could give us some insight in your workflow

Comment: i am using `rasa_core_sdk`. I am using `cmdline` channel.